# Count occurrence of strings in list of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I want to count the number of times a string has occurred in a list which is in another list and store it in a list of dictionary where each dictionary has count of a list.
Ex,

```py
list = [['Sam','John','Alex','Sam','Alex'],['Max','Sam','Max']...]
```

and I want my list of  dictionaries to be like:

```
count_list = [{'Sam':2,'Alex':2,'John':1}, {'Max':2, 'Sam':1}..]
```

I am iterating through each list to count number of times each string has occurred and adding each result to dict. But I end up having different result every time and not the correct values.

```py
count_list = []
for l in list :
    d = {}
    for str in l:
        if str not in d:
            d[str] = l.count(str)
            count_list.append(d)
```

Any help would be useful.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are doing the following:

```
count_list = []
for l in list :
    d = {}
    for str in l:
        if str not in d:
            d[str] = l.count(str)
            count_list.append(d)
```

Note that you are appending the dictionary for each string in the sub lists, rather than one dictionary per sub list.

Doing the following should address the issue:

```
count_list = []
for l in list :
    d = {}
    for str in l:
        if str not in d:
            d[str] = l.count(str)
    count_list.append(d)
```

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It would be easier to use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [["Sam", "John", "Alex", "Sam", "Alex"], ["Max", "Sam", "Max"]]
>>> list(map(Counter, lst))
[Counter({'Sam': 2, 'Alex': 2, 'John': 1}), Counter({'Max': 2, 'Sam': 1})]
```

You could also use a list comprehension instead of using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) if thats easier to understand:

```
>>> [Counter(l) for l in lst]
[Counter({'Sam': 2, 'Alex': 2, 'John': 1}), Counter({'Max': 2, 'Sam': 1})]
```

**Note:** `Counter` is a subclass of [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict), so you can treat them like normal dictionaries.

You can always cast to [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) if you want to as well:

```
>>> [dict(Counter(l)) for l in lst]
[{'Sam': 2, 'John': 1, 'Alex': 2}, {'Max': 2, 'Sam': 1}]
```

You should also not use `list` as a variable name, since it shadows the builtin function [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).